# Two clicks needed after checkbox & radio buttons are cleared with Javascript

Tags: javascript, button, click

I'm making a responsive menu based on the checkbox hack and am having a problem I can't seem to find anybody else having. Since the various dropdowns are controlled by checkboxes (hamburger menu) and radio buttons (menu item dropdowns, to avoid more than one being open at a time), they need to be cleared in a variety of situations so they don't stay open as the user explores the site - on browser resize, when clicking outside of the menu area, on page load for people who use the back button, etc. I don't know a word of Javascript, but I've pieced together code and learned some ultra-basic concepts by scrounging around various posts here and elsewhere that does the job for all of it. (It's all in vanilla Javascript except for one trigger that's in jQuery.)

The problem: when the checkboxes and radio buttons are cleared by the triggering of my "clearallbuttons" function, if the VERY NEXT THING YOU CLICK is whatever dropdown was open, it will take TWO clicks rather than one to re-open it - i.e. in the browser layout (768 pixels wide and up) if the "Test 1" dropdown is open and then you click outside the menu system or do anything else to trigger the "clearallbuttons" function, and then immediately click again on "Test 1," it will take two clicks to open the dropdown. (However, if "Test 1" was open and then gets triggered to close and the next thing you click is "Test 2" and THEN you click on "Test 1," there's no problem.) In the hamburger menu configuration, if you click on the hamburger menu and then - without opening "Test 1" or "Test 2" - trigger it to close (clicking outside of the menu dropdown, resizing the browser by turning your phone sideways, etc.), you will need to click on the hamburger menu TWICE to open it again. (However, if you DO open "Test 1" or "Test 2" in the hamburger dropdown and then trigger everything to close, there is no problem. The double-click error only happens if the first button you open after the trigger is the last button you clicked before the trigger.)

I have tried two different Javascript functions for clearing all the checkboxes and radio buttons in the menu. I get the same result from both. Here's one:

```
function clearallbuttons() {
  document.getElementById('form_resetter').reset();
```

And here's the other (this one doesn't require the otherwise extraneous Form field in the HTML markup):

```
function clearallbuttons(){
    var items=document.getElementsByName('menutoggle');
    for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        if(items[i].type=='radio','checkbox')
            items[i].checked=false;
    }
}
```

There is also Javascript on the page that allows the user to manually click a radio button to "off." So far as I can tell, this is not causing the problem.

Below are links to a live demo and the CSS, plus the HTML markup for the menu, and all the Javascript on the page. Maybe, as a Javascript ignoramus, I'm doing something wrong in the way I'm calling the function?

http://themoviedivision.com/menutest.php

http://themoviedivision.com/style.css

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cabin:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<header class="menuheader" id="fullmenu">
<form class="form_resetter" id="form_resetter" onsubmit="return false;">
  <a href="http://themoviedivision.com/menutest.php" class="logo">
    <img src="divisionlogo.png" height="20" width="116"></a>
    <ul class="socialicons">
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/themoviedivision"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://instagram.com/themoviedivision"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt14069588/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-imdb"></i></a></li>
    </ul>

  <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" name="menutoggle" />
  <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>

  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="menutest.php">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="menutest.php">Cast &amp; Crew</a></li>

<li>
  <input class="dropdown-btn" type="radio" id="dropdown-btn" name="menutoggle" />
  <label for="dropdown-btn"><a class="drop-select">Test 1</a></label>
     <div class="dropdown">
     <a href="#">Dropdown 1</a>
     <a href="#">Dropdown 2</a>
     <a href="#">Dropdown 3</a>
     </div>
</li>

<li>
  <input class="dropdown-btn2" type="radio" id="dropdown-btn2" name="menutoggle" />
  <label for="dropdown-btn2"><a class="drop-select">Test 2</a></label>
     <div class="dropdown2">
     <a href="#">Dropdown A</a>
     <a href="#">Dropdown B</a>
     <a href="#">Dropdown C</a>
     </div>
</li>

    <li><a href="menutest.php">JOIN US</a></li>


  </ul>
</form>
</header>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// allow radio buttons to be clicked off
var allRadios = document.getElementsByName('menutoggle');
var booRadio;
var x = 0;
for (x = 0; x < allRadios.length; x++) {

  allRadios[x].onclick = function() {

    if (booRadio == this) {
      this.checked = false;
      booRadio = null;
    } else {
      booRadio = this;
    }
  };

}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// define function to close all menu elements
function clearallbuttons() {
  document.getElementById('form_resetter').reset();
}

// close all menu elements on page load
window.onload = function() {
  clearallbuttons();
};

// close all menu elements on browser window resize
window.addEventListener("resize", clearallbuttons);

//close all menu elements when closing hamburger menu
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('#menu-btn').change(function() 
  {
    if(this.checked != true)
    {
         clearallbuttons();
    }
  });   
});

//close all menu elements when clicking outside the menu area
document.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
    const flyoutElement = document.getElementById("fullmenu");
    let targetElement = evt.target;

    do {
        if (targetElement == flyoutElement) {
            return;
        }
        targetElement = targetElement.parentNode;
    } while (targetElement);
    clearallbuttons();
});

</script>
```

(Credit where credit is due - I started with this CSS Nav code from "mutedblues" on Codepen - https://codepen.io/mutedblues/pen/MmPNPG - which includes a lovely all-CSS hamburger menu - and expanded from there.)

Thanks for any help!